# padding-left property is not working in Internet Explorer in visual studio 2010

Tags: html, css, asp.net

i am wondering that the css styles (`asp.net` project) that are working perfectly across the browsers, is failed to work with IE 11.

However to check whether it is really working or not I have wrote same styles and html in `jsfiddle', which you can find [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hitek_guy/vek1zdwz/8/), is also working perfectly.

I have no idea, where I am going wrong. Please make me correct.

`Code` below is `aspx` code.

```
<div class="fl pn whp contentbox">
<asp:Panel ID="LoginBox" CssClass="fl pn tlz centerLoginBox2" runat="server" > 
                 <h2 class="min bs pc h2color"> 
                    <span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#e611" class="icon-key"></span> Login
                 </h2>
                 <div class="fl tblogin pn whp">
                 <div class="pc whp mbot">
                 <asp:Label ID="lblUserName" runat="server" Text="User Id" 
                         CssClass="fl pn conText pcolor"></asp:Label>
                       <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserID" runat="server" CssClass="controlWidth txtborder" 
                          MaxLength="12" TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox>
                       <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="frvun" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter User Name" ControlToValidate="txtUserID" CssClass="required" Text="*" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </div>             

                 <div class="pc whp mbot">
                 <asp:Label ID="lblUserName" runat="server" Text="User Id" 
                         CssClass="fl pn conText pcolor"></asp:Label>
                       <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserPassword" runat="server" CssClass="controlWidth txtborder" 
                          MaxLength="12" TabIndex="1" Type="password"></asp:TextBox>
                       <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="frvun" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter password" ControlToValidate="txtUserID" CssClass="required" Text="*" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator> 

                       </div>
                       </div>
                 </div>      
                 </asp:Panel>
```

`Css styles` I have defined them in fiddle

Thank you!

Comment: I don't have an answer, but you have not translated the ASP.NET code to HTML properly for your fiddle. For instance, `<label  Text="User Id" />` is incorrect, in more than one way. You should use the resulting HTML from the ASP.NET page, by loading it into the browser and copying the relevant part from View Source.

Comment: @MrLister thank you so much for making me correct on html part. I have made it correct.  Thanks again!